# Icons not loading (empty image) in R Leaflet with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, icons, leaflet

[R-3.4.3 64-bit, RStudio, shinydashboard_0.6.1, shiny_1.0.5, leaflet.extras_0.2, Chrome]

I'm making icons to use in R/Leaflet with Shiny and all im getting is the below, but i've no idea why:

[image]

This is using the [toy example from here](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html):

```
oceanIcons <- iconList(
  ship = makeIcon("ferry-18.png", "ferry-18@2x.png", 18, 18),
  pirate = makeIcon("danger-24.png", "danger-24@2x.png", 24, 24)
)

# Some fake data
df <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(
  cbind(
    (runif(20) - .5) * 10 - 90.620130,  # lng
    (runif(20) - .5) * 3.8 + 25.638077  # lat
  ),
  data.frame(type = factor(
    ifelse(runif(20) > 0.75, "pirate", "ship"),
    c("ship", "pirate")
  ))
)

leaflet(df) %>% addTiles() %>%
  # Select from oceanIcons based on df$type
  addMarkers(icon = ~oceanIcons[type])
```

And the following, with different but similar toy data, when using `runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)`;

[image]

Comment: Have you got those icon files in your local drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [documentation for makeIcon](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/1.1.0/topics/makeIcon). As the first argument it expects:

```
iconUrl: the URL or file path to the icon image
```

So your code will only work if you either have the `png` in your working directory, alter the path so it contains the correct path to the image on your hard drive, or you could use an URL. So a working example would be:

```
  # Make a list of icons. We'll index into it based on name.
    oceanIcons <- iconList(
      ship = makeIcon("http://globetrotterlife.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/ferry-18.png", 18, 18),
      pirate = makeIcon("http://globetrotterlife.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/danger-24.png", 24, 24)
    )

    # Some fake data
    df <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(
      cbind(
        (runif(20) - .5) * 10 - 90.620130,  # lng
        (runif(20) - .5) * 3.8 + 25.638077  # lat
      ),
      data.frame(type = factor(
        ifelse(runif(20) > 0.75, "pirate", "ship"),
        c("ship", "pirate")
      ))
    )

    leaflet(df) %>% addTiles() %>%
      # Select from oceanIcons based on df$type
      addMarkers(icon = ~oceanIcons[type])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot, I actually just pasted the example directly but had used the full URL in my script, so I just could not see the error or what was going wrong. Turns out i forgot '.png' at the end of the url and was blind to it :/  feel free to delete the qu moderators

Comment: Hi @Sam, I think the answer displayed here does answer the question you posted, although that was not your actual question. It might be good to accept the answer anyway for any others that stumble into the same problem in the future, to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: If anyone's looking for the icons there's a zip of all the icons: http://globetrotterlife.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/mapicons.zip (no need to use wget, like I just did)

Comment: Also, apparently you can't use https. The https links to the icons is valid, but not accepted within R's Leaflet