# Local icons not loading, empty image in r leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio, r-leaflet

I am not able to display links to local images with `addControl`.

At first I thought my problem was the same as this question: [Icons not loading (empty image) in R Leaflet with Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944127/icons-not-loading-empty-image-in-r-leaflet-with-shiny). However, I noticed that when I tried to reproduce the example I ran into some issues.

I think these issues are related:

- R's Leaflet is not able to add markers for https (R Studio only)
- Leaflet within R Studio can not link to images when a relative or absolute local path is specified
- Leaflet within the R GUI is not able to link to images when a local path 
  is specified

I was surprised that some things were working in the R GUI and not R Studio. After inspecting the objects after they were rendered to HTML I found that the images are converted to base 64 objects. I think the issue is that the `makeIcon` is using this: `getFromNamespace(".b64EncodeFile", "markdown")`, and when adding HTML controls that link to a relative path there is no protocol so the object is not converted.

Here is my reproducible example:

```
library(leaflet)
data(quakes)
quakes <- quakes[1:10,]
leafIcons <- icons(
    iconUrl = ifelse(quakes$mag < 4.6,
                     "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
                     "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png"),
    iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
    iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94)
html_legend <- "<img src='data/icons/1.png'>green<br/>
<img src='C:/FULL_ABSOLUTE_PATH/data/icons/2.png'>red"
leaflet(data = quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons) %>%
    addControl(html = html_legend, position = "bottomleft")
```

The image rendered in R GUI
[image]

Same image in R Studio:
[image]

You'll need to copy these locally:

`1.png`: [image: PNG1]

`2.png`:[image: PNG2]

Comment: Does this work as you expect if you launch the leaflet visualization in a browser?

Comment: I think this may be a design decision made by RStudio not to allow access to random URLs in the IDE viewer - your icons seem to be just that. Here's a [discussion](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudioapi/issues/2) from a couple of years ago. Also, I don't know which version of the IDE you are using, but it might be possible that the situation could be different with the [1.2 preview IDE](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview).

Comment: When I export the map to a web page the full paths do work. I'm using R Studio 1.1.463.

Comment: I should separate this into two questions, but there are really two issues.

Comment: @geneorama did you find a solution to this? I am facing exactly the same problem. I considered placing the icons in the www folder, but this doesn't work locally.

Comment: @fifthace I believe I found two solutions. For that night at least I uploaded the icons to my personal website and linked to those. Later I found that specifying the full path worked.  So I used something like `icon_full_file <- file.path(getwd(), icon_data$file)`